# open/Save File Download not opening file in IE 6

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have used a code to download file it works well in IE7,, but in IE6 when i try to open the file (from open/save dialog box) its showing

> "The file could not be found.
>
> Try one or more of the following:
>
> - Check the spelling of the name of the document.
> - Try a different file name.
>
> (C:...\test[1].doc)"

The code i used is mention in this question i asked earlier
[Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition") not opening file in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889521/response-addheadercontent-disposition-not-opening-file-in-ie6)

Comment: mmm... wht to do to get answers soon....

Comment: i had found a solution and posted the code in above post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to Read and write content using  use Response.BinaryWrite(Content)
in order to download/open file in IE 6