# C# file export issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebresponse

I use this code to export/open files (pdf/xls/doc).

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
Response.ContentType = mimeType;

Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName + "." + extension);

Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.End();
```

When I open a doc file with Word and click export to xls or pdf, nothing happens until I close Word.
After I close Word I am already able to open xls and pdf too.

This problem exists when I open xls with Excel.

What is the reason?

Comment: Can't you set the `FileOpen` mode on the Stream.. can you show how you are declaring the stream..? also look at this posting for an example and try to use something like this `FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889521/response-addheadercontent-disposition-not-opening-file-in-ie6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the word version you use, I would say that the problem comes from the `inline` `content-disposition`

In recent versions of Word ( seen in Word 2010 ), it tries to open the document in `WEBDAV` mode when `inline`, which might cause issues (locks, missing cookies or credential when trying to export/print the document)

You may look at your network traffic to see if this WEBDAV behavior is involved, and see if `content-disposition` `attachment` solves the problem.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because Word, and other Word-like programs lock the open files to avoid double open again. So the locked file can not be opened again from your application.

Comment: With all due respect, I think this question belongs to SO.

Comment: The question about if this is a programming question or not has come up on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174144/158605)

Comment: @Rachel Ok, did know about meta, I delete the comments, and the line all ready deleted by Ben (nether vote to close or anything).

Comment: @Aristos No problem, I don't think I visited the meta site and really started to understand the community behind running the site until I had over 20k rep as well :)