# MS Word 2010 not showing image

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

I am generating a .docx file in a .net web application and providing it as a download URL for the users on the same page. The problem is, the same downloaded word document shows image on some systems and fails to show on some(Image refers to a external link). I compared all the settings related to word on both the systems and I didn't notice any difference.
Please give me some inputs on what might be causing this. All the systems I checked have windows 7 and MS word 2010.

Almost all the links which I referred suggest me to uncheck 'Show picture placeholders' option. But it's already disabled  in my case.

Thanks

Comment: webdav behaviour might be involved. You may give a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15704109/1236044

Comment: webdav is actually disabled on both the machines and it's already content-disposition attachment.

Answer (score 0):

please check Services Packs for all the systems.