# How to download a memory stream

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

I have a memory stream where I put the value of my PDF document.

my code is (in asp.net) will open a page in the browser containing the pdf content. what i want is download the pdf document instead of openning it during the browser

this is my code

```
// Send PDF to browser

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

document.Save(stream, false);

Response.Clear();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());

Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
Response.Flush();

stream.Close();

Response.End();
```

can u help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889521/response-addheadercontent-disposition-not-opening-file-in-ie6

Comment: [Do the google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195304/how-to-use-content-disposition-for-force-a-file-to-download-to-the-hard-drive)!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `Content-Disposition` header with `attachment` flag:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo.pdf");
```